# Viewbag not working in Explicit Partial View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, viewbag

I have a list view And i want to add a create partial to the page.

```
@model IEnumerable <blah.Domain.Entities.blah>
```

> @Html.Partial("_Quickblah", new blah.Domain.Entities.blah());

```
  public ViewResult _Quickblah()
        {
            ViewBag.CategoryID = new SelectList(Repository.Categorys, "CategoryID", "Title");

            Blah blah = new Blah () { CreatedDate = DateTime.Now };

            return View(blah);
        }
```

and i get the error

> There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that
>   has the key 'CategoryID'.

how can i fix this?

Comment: you are passing a model into a partial where does this contain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `Html.Partial` your `_Quickblah` controller action is not called and of course the `ViewBag.CategoryID` is not assigned (because I assume that in your main controller action that rendered this view you didn't set it). You should use `Html.Action` instead:

```
@Html.Action("_Quickblah")
```

Also in your `_Quickblah` action make sure that you are returning a partial view:

```
public ActionResult _Quickblah()
{
    ViewBag.CategoryID = new SelectList(Repository.Categorys, "CategoryID", "Title");
    Blah blah = new Blah () { CreatedDate = DateTime.Now };
    return PartialView(blah);
}
```

Comment: the error i got "CS1928: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<blah.Domain.Entities.blah>>' does not contain a definition for 'Partial' and the best extension method overload 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, string, object, System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, Could we use `@Html.Action()` ? Or when we prefer which is the better?

Comment: @Evildommer5, you should use `Html.Action()` instead of `Html.Partial()`. I have updated my answer.

Comment: There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'CategoryID'. Is my dropdown set properly?    @Html.DropDownList("CategoryID", string.Empty)

Comment: Did you replace the `@Html.Partial` with `@Html.Action`?

Comment: This now returns the error Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.

Comment: In your _Quickblah controller action replace `return View(blah);` with `return PartialView(blah);`

Comment: Do you have a view called `_Quickblah.cshtml` for the same controller? Also what's in the exception stacktrace?